# Simulate semi-monthly data from monthly data in Python

Tags: pandas

I am using Python with Sage Maker for forecasting time-series data and only have monthly data in hand which has a total of around 200 data points which is not enough for forecasting.

for example, I have

```
Jun 2013, 20, 30, 40
Jul 2013, 23, 33, 43.
```

What would do to generate things like:

```
06/01/2013, 20, 30, 40
06/10/2013, 21, 31, 41
06/20/2013, 22, 32, 42
07/01/2013, 23, 33, 43.
```

Comment: change to weekly is also fine, I just would need to simulate more data to train the model.

Comment: 1) please do not use the comments space for adding info - edit & update your post instead 2) the question has nothing to do with `numpy`, `machine-learning`, `lstm`, or `montecarlo` - kindly do not spam the tags (removed)

Comment: Thanks! This is part of numpy and a lstm model so I also add those tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the date to datetime , then we doing `resample` with `interpolate`

```
df.Date=pd.to_datetime(df.Date,format='%b %Y')
df.set_index('Date',inplace=True)
df.resample('10d').mean().interpolate(method='linear',axis=0)

Out[243]: 
              v1    v2    v3
Date                        
2013-06-01  20.0  30.0  40.0
2013-06-11  21.0  31.0  41.0
2013-06-21  22.0  32.0  42.0
2013-07-01  23.0  33.0  43.0
```